# How do I hide a property from the properties window in Compact Framework 3.5 / Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've created a derived control, which inherits from DataGrid.  I needed access to the scroll bars, so that I could reset the horizontal scroll bar to 0 each time a row is clicked.

My new property works great a run-time, but has an undesired effect at design-time, in that it throws an error and displays "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Since I don't want this property to be visible at design time, it would seem to me that what I need to do is hide my property in the Properties pane at design time.  I've tried adding `<Browsable(False)> _` before the property, but this causes the error "Type 'Browsable' is not defined."

Comment: Can you provide the entire atribute and method definition. It might be something as simple as the fact you dont have this on 2 lines or you are doing it to the class instead of a property or something. If I remove my imports for System.ComponentModel, I get your EXACT error, but as you mentioned in another comment, you have that.

Answer (score 0):

Have your imported the System.ComponentModel Namespace into your control project?

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
```

Comment: It's better to ask such shot questions in comment to the post.

Comment: Yes, I have the following at the top of my module:
`Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class MyDataGrid
    Inherits DataGrid
    Implements System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize`